# How to rewrite URL to hidden URL with parameter

Tags: tomcat6, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I want to use urlrewritefilter to have customer name and language in URL and pass them as parameter to a hidden url. So that the site will open customized. Everything which comes after the language slash should be pass to the hidden url

http://www.x.com/customer1/en/
rewrite to hidden url. customer should not see the following URL which should be called.

http://www.x.com/myapp/

and add following parameters
language=en
customerID=3

I am trying this rule but get always 404 http status error

```
<rule match-type="regex">
 <from>^/customer1/en/([A-Za-z0-9\._/]+)$</from>
 <set name="customerID">3</set> 
 <set name="language">en</set>
<to type="forward">/myapp/$1</to>

</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have one webapp with context-root = "/" (no cross-context).

Maybe you should activate the logs if it's not done, and see if your rule is called and **matched**.

You can activate log for urlrewritefilter in the filter config (see http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html#filterparams).

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
  <!-- sets up log level (will be logged to context log)
       can be: slf4j, TRACE, DEBUG, INFO (default), WARN, ERROR, FATAL,
       sysout:{level} (ie, sysout:DEBUG)
       if you are having trouble using normal levels use sysout:DEBUG
       (default WARN) -->
  <init-param>
    <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
    <param-value>DEBUG</param-value>
  </init-param>

</filter>
```

You must also add the dependencies for the logging, like slf4j-api, slf4j-log4j12, log4j-1.2.